# ArcMap Time Slider-> features disappear when I enable time function!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, timeslider

When I go to the properties and enable the time function, seen in the screen clip 1, and then click OK or apply, my polygons (and their attributes)disappear and are not visable in the time slider tool, see screen clip 2. I don't understand why?

I can get my data back by disabling the time function. I am using ArcMap 10.3.

screen clip 1
[image]

screen clip 2
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be that time was not specified in the date columns. Once I added "00:00" to the exsisting dates, the time slider function worked.